# Scala - How to call a future function while mapping over a Seq?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

I have a `Seq[String]`, and these string values are needed to call another function defined as:

```
def getSomethingById(id: String): Future[Someting]
```

I'm trying to create a function which takes the `Seq[String]` and returns `Future[Seq[Something]]`; i.e.,

```
def getSomethings(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[Something]]
```

The only way to get the `Something` type is by calling the `getSomethingById` method above.

Is there a way I can map over the `Seq[String]`, then call `getSomethingById`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Future.sequence` for this:

```
def getSomethings(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[Something]] =
  Future.sequence(ids.map(getSomethingById))
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future%24.html

> Simple version of Future.traverse. Asynchronously and non-blockingly
>   transforms a TraversableOnce[Future[A]] into a
>   Future[TraversableOnce[A]]. Useful for reducing many Futures into a
>   single Future.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In addition to existing answer you can also use `Future.traverse` which is very similar

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
       import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


def getSomethingById(id: String): Future[String] = Future{
  id + "from Something Id"
}

def getSomethings(ids: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[String]] = 
       Future.traverse(ids)(getSomethingById)

scala> getSomethingById: (id: String)scala.concurrent.Future[String]
scala> getSomethings: (ids: Seq[String])scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]]
```

### Test

```
scala> getSomethings(Range.apply(1,3).map(_.toString))
res0: Vector(1from Something Id, 2from Something Id)
```